# Cbor address to bech32 type address in JS or python

Tags: api, javascript, cbor, python

I have managed to retrive a user address from a dapp connector wallet using JS:

```
api_promise = window.cardano.{wallet}.enable();
api_promise.then(function(api) {
  addr_promise = api.getUsedAddresses();
  addr_promise.then(
    function(addr) {
      value[0];  // this is a CBOR address !
...
```

I get this type of (presumably CBOR) address: `012f4d0b584ecb52e4e4b8e78e4ce77a6f822e59ede3277305fd526b71824b2d2740284cf6a28e2a512cc4a00f41004c18ed728a0f7a04eb29`
Apparently with some skill it could be read using this -> `https://cbor.me`.

**# Is there any method to extract a shelley `addr_34....` using JS or python?**

Working implementations are available in node.js, but I'm using flask (python + JS). And I'm struggling to make it work wit packages `cbor2` and `bech32`.
For example I tried `cbor2.loads(bytes(addr_str, 'utf-8'))` without success.

My further goal is to query blockfrost.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [typhonjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stricahq/typhonjs) used by typhonwallet. It's a Pure JS library not dependent on WASM.

Install

```
npm i @stricahq/typhonjs
```

Usage

```
const typhonjs =  require("@stricahq/typhonjs");

const bech32Address = typhonjs.utils
  .getAddressFromHex("012f4d0b584ecb52e4e4b8e78e4ce77a6f822e59ede3277305fd526b71824b2d2740284cf6a28e2a512cc4a00f41004c18ed728a0f7a04eb29")
  .getBech32();
```

Comment: I might appear clueless, but I am running code via python Flask. It means the javascript is executed client-side. In the background, everything is executed via python and ajax queries. Will I be able to execute this client side?

Comment: Yes, you can execute this code client side :) @Lokinou

Answer (score 1):

First install the npm module:

```
npm i @emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser
```

Then you need a wasm loader module

```
class wasm {
  async load() {
    if (this._wasm) return;
    /**
     * @private
     */
    this._wasm = await import(
      "@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib"
    );
  }

  get Cardano() {
    return this._wasm;
  }
}

export default new wasm();
```

Then import into your module/component using:

```
import WASMLoader from "../../utils/Loader";
```

Now you should be able to use wasm module to convert the CBOR address into bech32 (addr1.., stake1.. etc)

```
const getAddressToBech32 = async () => {
    await WASMLoader.load();
    const address = (await api.getUsedAddresses())[0];
    return WASMLoader.Cardano.Address.from_bytes(Buffer.from(address,"hex")).to_bech32();
};
```

Now that you have a bech32 address you should be able to use with for blockfrost API queries